# trying to get hands on angular Routing concepts BUT when try to reload the page NOTHING HAS BEEN SHOWN up.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

I working on this in editor Bracket and I created bunch of files and file structure can be seen in under scripts tags under Index.html 
the root folder names is projectAngular under which there is folder appCntrl -->controller--->(all the controllers files).Also Under folder views-->customers.html and under script==>[angular and angular route files]

Index.html is at root "projectAngular" folder

while trying to run this application I can only see BLANK screen. I check my script tags under index.html. appears good. Also under controller I think i gave dependencies also. I am not sure what exactly is happening here or the angular version i am using is outdated.

Pls HELP!!!! thanks

I created exact in Plunkr . Below is the URL

http://plnkr.co/edit/WVAglImSEKQkQA1BaAUZ?p=catalogue

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">

<head>
  <title> Iterating over Data</title>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Here on Below Line I am loading the view through ngRoute directive declared
           on "customerController" and "routes" declared on "appRoute.js" with view file
           on customer.html -->

  <div ng-view=""></div>



  <!--
    <h2>Customers</h2>
    <br/> FILTER:
    <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name">{{customerFilter.name}}
    <br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>

            <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>

            <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">OrderTotal</th>

            <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | orderBy:sortBy:reverse |filter:customerFilter">
            <td>{{cust.name| uppercase}}</td>

            <td>{{cust.city | lowercase}}</td>

            <td>{{cust.orderTotal | currency}}</td>

            <td>{{cust.joined | date}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <span>Total Customers: {{customers.length}}</span>
-->

  <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/angular-routes.js"></script>
  <script src="appCntrl/controller/appRoute.js"></script>
  <script src="appCntrl/controller/customerController.js"></script>
</body>
```

customer.html

```
<h2>Customers</h2>
<br/> FILTER:
<input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name">{{customerFilter.name}}
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>

    <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>

    <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">OrderTotal</th>

    <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | orderBy:sortBy:reverse |filter:customerFilter">
    <td>{{cust.name| uppercase}}</td>

    <td>{{cust.city | lowercase}}</td>

    <td>{{cust.orderTotal | currency}}</td>

    <td>{{cust.joined | date}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
```

### Total Customers: {{customers.length}}

customerController.js file

```
(function() {

  var customerApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

  // It helps angular to realize what params are being passed to controller if minification has replaced the variables 
  customerController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function customerController($scope) {
    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;

    $scope.customers = [{
      name: 'kevin',
      city: 'San Farnando',
      orderTotal: '10.78',
      joined: '1990-12-10'
    }, {
      name: 'ketty',
      city: 'Seattle',
      orderTotal: '12.99',
      joined: '2003-4-7'
    }, {
      name: 'John',
      city: 'Texas',
      orderTotal: '6.787',
      joined: '2015-9-9'
    }, {
      name: 'Jackson',
      city: 'ohio',
      orderTotal: '12.00',
      joined: '2003-12-1'
    }];
    $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
      $scope.sortBy = propName;
      $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };

  }
  customerApp.controller('customerController', customerController);
}());
```

---

appRoute.js

```
(function() {

  var customerApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

  customerApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        controller: 'customerController',
        templateurl: 'views/customer.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });

}());
```

Comment: I'm only adding this as a comment because I'm not sure if this will solve the problem or even if it's just nonsense, but, consider making the module's second argument an empty array in customerController.js . I've had problems with injecting on all pages except the app page

Comment: @BillPope  I tried it but its not working. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can try a simpler example, like just one js and two static pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`templateurl` needs to be `templateUrl`.

Your plunkr has many mistakes:

1. You need to update the paths in plunkr to point at the root, there are no folders within plunkr.
2. Use external angular files, because otherwise, your plunkr size is too big and fails to load.

[Updates to your plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ixI2vmz785jC0vad8z4M?p=preview) that made it work.

Comment: it worked . I just pointed to angular CDN rather than pointing to file and corrected spelling.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. The first thing you need to do is to make sure that:

   ```
   angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
   ```

is used only once.

In your controller, you need to use:

```
    var customerApp = angular.module('demoApp');
```

Adding the empty brackets instantiates a new angular module which you don't want to do here.

2. In your appRoute.js file, make sure the templateUrl points to the correct file.
3. Remove  and replace with .

Comment: @pankajparkar as far as the plunkr example is concerned, you might have to reroute the script tags. They're currently pointed to directories that don't exist